# calling same function multiple places for same job

Tags: c++

I have the following code where `EnableForm()` is called in response to various conditions. Now I had to add one more condition and this makes it even more complex. How can I simply it?

```
void CValidateDialog::ProcessTime(string time, const int min, const int max)
{
    if (!time.empty())
    {
        if (min > 100 && max < 200)
            EnableForm(TRUE);
        else
            EnableForm(FALSE);

        // Now I had to add one more condition which make this even more complex
        // this should ideally be tied to the above condition
        COleDateTime curDateTime = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

        if (curDateTime.GetHour() < 12)
            EnableForm(TRUE);
        else
            EnableForm(FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        EnableForm(FALSE);
    }
}
```

How can I simplify this and make it more readable?

One approach I can us is below but even that is not so readable.

```
void CValidateDialog::ProcessTime(string time, const int min, const int max)
{
    BOOL bEnable = FALSE;

    if (!time.empty())
    {
        if (min > 100 && max < 200)
            bEnable = TRUE;

        // additional possible criteria make this more complex, for example:
        COleDateTime curDateTime = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

        // will proceed only bEnable is FALSE so have to add this to condition
        if (!bEnable && (curDateTime.GetHour() < 12))
            bEnable = TRUE;
    }

    EnableForm(bEnable);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context about what this code is doing and why. It would be good to explain what the parameters mean, as well as what `EnableForm()` does. Also change the title to state what the code does. (See [ask].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, `FALSE` and `TRUE` actually correspond closely to `false` and `true` respectively. That being the case, I'd at least consider computing the correct values, and passing them directly to `EnableForm`, rather than always using an `if`/`else` to pass literals:

```
void CValidateDialog::ProcessTime(string time, const int min, const int max)
{
    bool in_range = min > 100 && max < 200;   
    bool morning = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime().GetHour() < 12;

    EnableForm(!time.empty() && in_range && morning);
}
```

This does have one weakness: it always does all the computing for all the conditions. The original won't even look at the current time (for example) if the `time` parameter is empty. If the calculations involved were expensive, you might want to avoid this. For one obvious way, you could cram everything together into a single expression:

```
EnableForm(!time.empty() &&
           min > 100 && 
           max < 200 &&
           COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime().GetHour() < 12);
```

I don't think this is quite as readable, but thanks to short-circuit evaluation, it'll stop evaluation of the sub-expressions as soon as it gets to one that produces `false`, which *could* save significant time in at least some cases.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful but I think even if it evaluates all the conditions, it really shouldn't not be that bad at least in most cases.